# Run process remotely from an http page

Tags: javascript, html, server

I'm using OBS-WebSocket.js as a component (available on server) to call for change the OBS scenes, through OBS websockets. This way is compatible with all platforms, I can load the main html page from server and clicking a button I can switch the scenes.

I would find a way now to kill and reload OBS in case it hangs, from the same http page, I?m asking if there is a similar way to start a process on server, I mean:
a process running on server, listening on a tcp port and ready to start a batch file (or python script)
a .js file to invoke from the http page, able to send a proper command to that listening port.

There is something like this already? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a simple [Express](https://expressjs.com/) server that listens to HTTP POST requests on e.g. `/restart`. You can use the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module to spawn a process and later on kill it.